# Trying to use xcode with pascal language

Tags: xcode, pascal

i want to learn pascal language , for that i'm currently using xcode .
I I installed Free Pascal, but now I do not know how to open a document in xcode.
infact I would just write a simple program and see my mistakes  .
I opened FPC Carbon, but I do not know what to do next.

Best regards

Comment: I spent a bit of time looking for tutorials via Google for you but there isn't much that shows steps of what to do with Xcode 4 versus FPC.  I suspect the next thing you'll have to do is [sign up with the various FPC mailing lists](http://www.freepascal.org/maillist.var) and ask for advice and/or guidance.

Answer (score 0):

See the XCode templates on this page:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/28343282/ObjP/index.html

Comment: i have a last question : I started somehow with xcode and I would write a simple program to train me. or is it that I can do this after opening a project

Comment: I happened to know this because I have Macs and FPC, and thus am on the Mac Pascal list. But I use Lazarus mostly as IDE, so I don't know much about XCode.

Comment: The link seems outdated